# How to use asyncpostbacktrigger in the datagrid editcommandcolumn

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Asp.Net page I use DataGrid .In DataGrid editcommandcolumn is use for update and cancel.my requirement is if we update click is happen fire the asyncpostbacktrigger   works.Is it possible or not